# Setting dynamic background image in React with create react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In the following TSX/JSX, the background image doesn't load properly, because the URL is not changed during transpile, and so it points to the wrong location.

I assume it's a webpack config issue. In the past, I've manually set up React apps, but I'm fairly new to create react-app. Do I need to eject and do some manual config, or is there a better approach to dynamically loading background images that I'm missing?

```
{section.stops.map(s => (
  <div 
    className="tour-stop"
    style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(./img/${s.imagePath})`
    }}
  >
       blah blah blah
  </div>
 ))}
```

Comment: The url won't change during compile, it's dynamically set at run-time

Comment: Thanks. That actually makes a lot of sense, and I don't know how I missed that. Is there an obvious way to access the process environment? I've tried that, and the URL I get is an empty string.

Comment: You're welcome - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by process environment, however I can show you how to implement a component the renders background images as required (provided you have those image url's already)

Comment: That would be lovely, if you don't mind and have the time.

Comment: @erfing - just posted an answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically set background images for the `stops` that are rendered for your component consider wrapping the list of items returned from `render()` with an element such as a `<div>` or `<React.Fragment>`, rather than the `{ .. }` brackets as shown below:

```css
.tour-stop {
  padding:5rem;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="module"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

class DemoComponent extends React.Component { 
   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    /* Prepopulate the state of the component with image data for subsequnet the render */
    this.state = {

        section : {
            stops : [
                { imagePath : 'https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/background-wallpapers-26.jpg' },
                { imagePath : 'https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/704532.jpg' },
                { imagePath : 'https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/abstract-background-design_1297-88.jpg' }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
    
  render() {
  
      /* Access the section object from state, by which the stops will be rendered */
      const { section } = this.state;

      /* Ensure that the list result returned is wrapped with an element. Usually 
         <div> is used to wrap results however <React.Fragment> can also be useful */
      return <div>{ 
        section.stops.map(s => (<div 
          className="tour-stop" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${s.imagePath})` }}>
            blah blah blah
          </div>))
      }</div>
  }
}

  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <DemoComponent />
    </div>, 
  document.getElementById("module"));
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It's definitely true that putting the images somewhere where they can be accessed by full path would work. Not what I was hoping for, but it is a workaround I can use for now. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @erfling you're welcome - let me know if there's anything else I can do to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to hard-code any URL that comes within your directory. You have to write a condition that selects the exact image. This is not the case if its a URL that comes from DB/anywhere else.

an example from your code would be (without any coding) is,

if `s.imagePath` is `'val1'`, use this image: `'./img/1.jpeg'` if not, use whatever.

This only happens when you are getting assets within your own directory.

Comment: Is there an obvious way to do this that will work both in dev and deployment?

Comment: @erfling by absolute path, I meant hard-coded path. currently yours is a dynamic path. dynamic paths don't work if the asset is coming from the directory. will edit my answer

Comment: @erfling and this has nothing to do with prod or dev environments

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```js
 <div className="drag-dashboard" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${config.DESTINATION_MEDIA_CDN+ "assets/icons_skining/upload_placeholder_skining.png"})`}}> </div>
```